# Bootstrap4 Radio Buttons Bug

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

hello i have added a modal form to reserve a table and yet i see circles in the buttons the code from 229 to 241 is the modal and cannot remove the circles from the form thats the code the link for the file https://github.com/ahmedabdo97/bootstrap4/blob/master/index.html Screenshot for error https://github.com/ahmedabdo97/bootstrap4/blob/master/Error.png

```
                     <div class="form-group row col-12">
                                                <div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
                                                        <label class="col-12 col-md-3 mr-auto col-form-label">Sections</label>
                                                        <div class=" col-12 ml-4">
                                                        <label class="btn btn-success active">
                                                          <input type="radio" name="non-smoking" id="non-smoking" autocomplete="off" checked> Non-Smoking
                                                         </label>
                                                        <label class="btn btn-danger">
                                                           <input type="radio" name="smoking" id="smoking" autocomplete="off"> Smoking
                                                         </label>
                                                        </div>
                                                      </div>
                                        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Remove the code which I have pasted below in your code.**

```html
<label class="btn btn-success active">
<input type="radio" name="non-smoking" id="non-smoking" autocomplete="off" checked> Non-Smoking
</label>
<label class="btn btn-danger">
 <input type="radio" name="smoking" id="smoking" autocomplete="off"> Smoking
   </label>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have put radio inputs inside of the button i.e.

```
<input type="radio" name="smoking" id="smoking" autocomplete="off">
```

Simply removing these will take care of the circles(fyi these are used for radio button(single option select input field values).